# Angular Material Theming - dynamically add themes without rebuilding

Tags: angular, typescript, themes, angular-material

I use Angular material theming in my project and I can switch easily between my custom themes.

Now I want to add a custom theme without rebuilding the entire application. The aim is to allow users to create their own themes and use it directly.

Is this possible with Angular Material ? Or are there any other methods to do this?

Comment: have you had any luck?? I am facing this issue as well.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem now, but no answers yet ... Have you found a solution?

Comment: I will add myself to the list.  As far as I am aware, you must build but this is pretty limiting to a white label project.